# How do I restore my yakuake.knsrc file on kubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, kubuntu

I deleted my `yakuake.knsrc` file. Now I cannot configure `Yakuake`. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling. Didn't work. Can anyone please help me restore my copy of `yakuake.knsrc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be [here in the source code](https://github.com/KDE/yakuake/blob/master/app/yakuake.knsrc) for Yakuake. Copied and pasted here for reference.

```
[KNewStuff3]
Categories=Yakuake Skin
Uncompress=always
TargetDir=yakuake/kns_skins
```